# How make NSWindow movable on Mac Screen using SwiftUI?

Tags: xcode, macos, swiftui

I want to create a borderless custom view that can be draggable on full screen of Mac using floating property.
But when I created borderless NSWindow. It is not moving and when I make movable its shows titlebar.
I want a borderless with no title-bar and can be draggable on full screen of mac. here is the sample code

```
let frame = NSScreen.main!.frame
        window = NSWindow(
            contentRect: frame,
            styleMask: [.borderless],
            backing: .buffered,
            defer: false
        )
        window.makeKeyAndOrderFront(nil)
        window.isMovable = true // Make the window movable

        // Embed the ContentView as the root view of the window
        let contentView = ContentView()
        window.contentView = NSHostingView(rootView: contentView)
```

Comment: I assume you want this: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nswindow/1419072-movablebywindowbackground

Comment: @jnpdx can you provide me simple code for mac using swiftui?

Comment: `window.isMovableByWindowBackground = true` (note that this doesn't have anything to do with SwiftUI -- you're already creating your window via AppKit)